# How to generate a frequency table from a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a df with raw survey data similar to the following with 12000 rows and forty questions. All responses are categorical

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Age' : ['20-30','20-30','30-45', '20-30','30-45','20-30'],
                   'Gender' : ['M', 'F', 'F','F','M','F'],
                   'Income' : ['20-30k', '30-40k', '40k+', '40k+', '40k+', '20-30k'],
                   'Question1' : ['Good','Bad','OK','OK','Bad','Bad'],
                   'Question2' : ['Happy','Unhappy','Very_Unhappy','Very_Unhappy','Very_Unhappy','Happy']})
```

I  want to categorize the responses to each question according to Age, Gender and Income, to produce a frequency (by %) table for each question that looks like this [screenshot showing questions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1sBGk.png).

[image]

Crosstab produces too many categories ie it breaks down by income and within income, by age etc. So I'm not sure how best to go about this. I'm sure this is an easy problem but I'm new to python to any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you said, using cross tab for all the columns breaks down the result by each column. You can use individual cross tabs and then concat

```
pd.concat([pd.crosstab(df.Question1, df.Gender), pd.crosstab(df.Question1, df.Income), pd.crosstab(df.Question1, df.Age)], axis = 1)

            F   M   20-30k  30-40k  40k+    20-30   30-45
Question1                           
Bad         2   1   1       1       1       2       1
Good        0   1   1       0       0       1       0
OK          2   0   0       0       2       1       1
```

Edit: To get additional level at columns

```
age = pd.crosstab(df.Question1, df.Age)
age.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Age'], age.columns])
gender = pd.crosstab(df.Question1, df.Gender)
gender.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Gender'], gender.columns])
income = pd.crosstab(df.Question1, df.Income)
income.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['Income'], income.columns])
pd.concat([age, gender, income], axis = 1)


        Age             Gender  Income
        20-30   30-45   F   M   20-30k  30-40k  40k+
Question1                           
Bad     2       1       2   1   1       1       1
Good    1       0       0   1   1       0       0
OK      1       1       2   0   0       0       2
```

Comment: Perfect. Thank you so much

Comment: @zepaft Just a reminder, don't forget to mark it as 'answer' if it solves your question.

Comment: Finding a new way : -)

Answer (score 2):

You can do `melt` before `crosstab`

```
s=df.drop('Question2',1).\
     melt(['Age','Gender','Income']).drop('variable',1).\
        rename(columns={'value':'v1'}).melt('v1')

pd.crosstab(s.v1,[s.variable,s.value])
Out[235]: 
variable   Age       Gender    Income            
value    20-30 30-45      F  M 20-30k 30-40k 40k+
v1                                               
Bad          2     1      2  1      1      1    1
Good         1     0      0  1      1      0    0
OK           1     1      2  0      0      0    2
```